# How to access an nested object within another object in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to iterate through an object to access another object using typescript/javascript, but I am not sure how to point to a specific location within the complex object since the key is changing.

Here is my object:

```
{
    "external": {
        "enum": {
            "value": null,
            "type": "enum"
        }
    },
    "external_internal": {
        "enum": {
            "value": "",
            "type": "enum"
        }
    },
    "internal": {
        "text": {
            "value": "test",
            "type": "text"
        }
    }
}
```

Right now, I am trying to iterate through each object to check if the `value` key has a null or blank value. If it does, it splices it out of the original object for a return of

```
{
    "internal": {
        "enum": {
            "value": "test",
            "type": "enum"
        }
    }
}
```

Right now, if I try to access a object using `myObj[0]`, I get a undefined error.

My attempt:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myObj.length; i++) {
    if (myObj[i][0].value === null || '') {

        delete myObj[i]


    }

}
```

Comment: expected should internal with next objected having property 'text' , what is logic of changeing it to enum?

Comment: *"if I try to access a object using `myObj[0]`"*. You are not working with an array, you're working with an object, `[0]` is for arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a `for` loop to iterat through an `Object`, `reduce` the `Object.entries` and check if the `value` is `null` or empty string by looping through the `Object.values` :

```js
const obj = {
  external: {
    enum: {
      value: null,
      type: "enum"
    }
  },
  external_internal: {
    enum: {
      value: "",
      type: "enum"
    }
  },
  internal: {
    text: {
      value: "test",
      type: "text"
    }
  }
};

const result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((all, [key, o]) => {
  var keepIt = false;

  Object.values(o).forEach(e => {
    if (e.value) keepIt = true;
  });

  if (keepIt) all[key] = o;

  return all;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below option of using reduce with Object.entries

1. Use reduce to loop Object.entries of object
2. Check value of nested object
3. If value exists , push to accumulator and return it

```js
var obj = {
    "external": {
        "enum": {
            "value": null,
            "type": "enum"
        }
    },
    "external_internal": {
        "enum": {
            "value": "",
            "type": "enum"
        }
    },
    "internal": {
        "text": {
            "value": "test",
            "type": "text"
        }
    }
}


console.log(Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, v) => {
  if(Object.entries(v[1])[0][1].value){
    acc[v[0]] = v[1];
  }
  return acc
}, {}));
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/vYBgXRJ